# Is there a generic function that identifies the cases of a nested discriminated union?

Tags: f#, nested, discriminated-union

I created a nested Discriminated Union (DU) as follows:

```
type OptimizationPeriod = | All
                          | Long
                          | Short

type OptimizationCriterion = | SharpeRatio      of OptimizationPeriod
                             | InformationRatio of OptimizationPeriod
                             | CalmarRatio      of OptimizationPeriod
```

and also a non-nested DU:

```
type Parallelism = Sequential | PSeq
```

I have a JSON configuration file with strings that define the DU cases. The following function manages to identify the case of the non-nested `Parallelism` DU :

```
let stringToDUCase<'t> (name: string) : 't =
        let dUCase =
            Reflection.FSharpType.GetUnionCases( typeof<'t> )
            |> Seq.tryFind (fun uc -> uc.Name = name)
            |> Option.map (fun uc -> Reflection.FSharpValue.MakeUnion( uc, [||] ) :?> 't)
        match dUCase with
        | Some x -> x
        | _ -> let msg = sprintf "config.json - %s is not a case in DU %A" name typeof<'t>
               failwith msg
```

Note: I certainly copied it from somewhere as the function is a bit over my head, apologies to the author for not remembering where it came from.

Unfortunately this function fails to identify the case for the nested DU:

```
stringToDUCase<OptimizationCriterion> config.Trading.Criterion
System.Exception: config.json - SharpeRatio All is not a case in DU FractalTypes.OptimizationCriterion
```

Two questions:

1) I was able to write a function that deals `specifically` with the `OptimizationCriterion` DU and is able to identify the case. Is there a `generic` function along the lines of `stringToDUCase` that could do the same?

2) Would it be better to use a tuple of type `OptimizationCriterion*OptimizationPeriod` instead of a nested DU? (I probably would have to call `stringToDUCase` twice, but that is not a problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An "empty" DU case like `All` is just a value, but a "non-empty" DU case like `SharpeRatio` is actually a function that takes one value and returns the type. In this case, `SharpeRatio` has the type `OptimizationPeriod -> OptimizationCriterion`.

Your existing `stringToDUCase` function always passes an empty array into `MakeUnion` (implying an empty DU case). So here's a modified version of the function that works for any DU case:

```
let stringToParamDUCase<'t> (name: string) =
    Reflection.FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<'t>)
    |> Seq.tryFind (fun uc -> uc.Name = name)
    |> Option.map (fun uc ->
        fun (parameters:obj []) -> Reflection.FSharpValue.MakeUnion(uc, parameters) :?> 't)
    |> Option.defaultWith (fun () ->
        failwith (sprintf "config.json - %s is not a case in DU %A" name typeof<'t>))
```

Note that it returns a function of `obj [] -> 't`. I've also simplified the error handling a little bit.

This is how you might use it:

```
let myOptimizationPeriod = stringToParamDUCase<OptimizationPeriod> "All" [||]
let f = stringToParamDUCase<OptimizationCriterion> "SharpeRatio"
let myOptimizationCriterion = f [|All|]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the existing answer should answer your question directly. However, I think it is worth making two additional points. First, it might be easier if you represented your `OptimizationCriterion` as a record, because all your DU cases contain the same value:

```
type OptimizationPeriod = 
  | All | Long | Short

type OptimizationRatio = 
  | SharpeRatio | InformationRatio | CalmanRatio

type OptimizationCriterion =
  { Ratio : OptimizationRatio
    Period : OptimizationPeriod }
```

This happens to solve your problem too, because now you only need DUs without parameters, but I think it is also better design, because you avoid duplicating the second parameter.

Second, I don't think you really need to go with a fancy custom reflection-based function for deserialization. If you want to store your data in a JSON, you should either use standard library (Newtonsoft.JSON or Chiron will do just fine), or you can write this directly using something like `JsonValue` from F# Data, but using custom reflection code is a quick way leading to unmaintainable code.

Comment: Ok, I had myself raised the hypothesis of using a tuple to represent `OptimizationCriterion`. Using a record is even better. Both tuples and records are product types. OTOH I looked at JsonValue and could not figure out how to use it to transform a string (that is what the `Json` type provider gives me) into a DU. The data did not originate from the program. It was entered manually, sort of like in a Windows .ini file.